# User Profile Synchronization - Filter by AD OU or DN attributes

Tags: 2010, active-directory, user-profile-service, filter, synchronisation

I am attempting to filter out a subset of users in Active Directory from being pulled into the User Profile Service. The users need to be filtered by the Organizational Unit property (ou), which is also present in the Distinguished Name property (dn).

So I'm trying to do this by editing the connection filters on my AD User Profile Synchronization Service connection, however I can't get it to work using an `ou Contains blah` filter. "dn" is not an option in the drop down to filter by.

How can I prevent these users from being imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rectified this by editing the User Profile Service Synchronization Connection to Active Directory (Central Admin > Manage Service Applications > User Profile Service > Configure Synchronization Connections > Select Connection > Edit).

Then I just deselected the specific OUs in the Containers window. It takes a few seconds (or sometimes 20) to load once you click to deselect the OU so be patient. It's working on it.