# Can I synchronize only users that are members of a certain AD group?

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-service

I have a user profile service application set up, and now I want to import profiles from an AD, but I don't want all users, only those that are members of a given AD group. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the User Profile Service Synchronization Connection to Active Directory (Central Admin > Manage Service Applications > User Profile Service > Configure Synchronization Connections > Select Connection > Edit).

Then only select the specific group in the Containers window, and save. This will limit the User Profile Service Synchronization to only synchronize this group.

See: [User Profile Synchronization - Filter by AD OU or DN attributes](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41488/user-profile-synchronization-filter-by-ad-ou-or-dn-attributes)

Comment: This would be OK, but the list of groups is long and is truncated. The group I'm looking for doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try a different browser or try to turn off `overflow:auto;` on the container from within your F12 Developer Tools, though I'm not sure that would fix the issue. The scroll bar should automatically appear if the contents are larger than the container size. The tree view is an .axd Ajax HTTP Handler that communicates asynchronously with your AD forest. Try playing with the Developer Tools.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it's not an HTML rendering issue. It's as if the server caps the list of groups.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to tell you about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a LDAP filter to the synchronization connection if you are using AD import.

If you open the User Profile Service Application, then click on 'Configure Synchronization Connections', then click on the dropdown for your current synchronization connection and click 'Edit'.

Then under 'Filter in LDAP syntax for Active Directory Import' you can insert your LDAP query. To query for membership of a specific group you can use a LDAP query like the following:

```
(memberOf=CN=MyADGroupName,ou=Users,dc=myDomain,dc=com)
```

The option to change to AD import can be found under User Profile Service Application - Configure Synchronization Settings.